# Rationalizing mixed denominators?

Tags: radicals

How would I rationalize the following Fraction?

$$ \frac {2}{5-\sqrt2+\sqrt3}$$

I have considered the idea of multiplying by the same radicals, but the 5 prevents that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\frac{2}{5-\sqrt2+\sqrt3}\left(\frac{5+\sqrt2-\sqrt3}{5+\sqrt2-\sqrt3}\right)&=\frac{10+2\sqrt2-2\sqrt3}{20+2\sqrt6}\\
&=\frac{10+2\sqrt2-2\sqrt3}{20+2\sqrt6}\left(\frac{20-2\sqrt6}{20-2\sqrt6}\right)\\
&=\frac{200-20\sqrt6+40\sqrt2-4\sqrt{12}-40\sqrt3+4\sqrt{18}}{400-24}\\
&=\frac{200-20\sqrt6+52\sqrt2-48\sqrt3}{376}\\
&=\frac{50-5\sqrt6+13\sqrt2-12\sqrt3}{94}\\
&\approx.37609
\end{align}$$
You can check you answer [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rationalize+2%2F%285-sqrt2%2Bsqrt3%29)

Comment: Thanks! I'm writing a program to rationalize radicals, I think this is how I'll do it :)

Comment: @BillyK No problem.  On MSE, if one answer is the most helpful, we accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply top and bottom by all the "relatives" $5+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$, $5+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ and $5-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$.

The new denominator is invariant under replacement of $\sqrt{2}$ by $-\sqrt{2}$, also under replacement of $\sqrt{3}$ by $-\sqrt{3}$, so it must be rational.

Comment: +1 - the 'baby Galois' view is a really nice way of looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Rationalize the denominator using the product of the terms below

$\quad \begin{eqnarray}(5\!+\!\sqrt3-\sqrt2)(5\!+\!\sqrt3+\sqrt2) &\,=\,& (5\!+\!\sqrt3)^2-2 &\,=\,&26+10\sqrt3\\  
(5\!-\!\sqrt3-\sqrt2)(5\!-\!\sqrt3+\sqrt2) &=& (5\!-\!\sqrt3)^2-2  &=&26-10\sqrt3\end{eqnarray}\Bigg\rbrace$ multiplied $ \,=\, \ldots$